# MySql not sorting properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset and after performing the order by, I get this:

```
 +------+
 |Emp_ID|
 +------+
 | E1   |
 | E10  |
 | E3   |
 | E4   |
 | E5   |
 +------+
```

I am executing the following query:

`select emp_id from employee_master_table order by emp_id`

Why `E10` instead of `E3` is coming after `E1` ?

Comment: E10 should come after E1, this is a string and hence the sort is Alphabetic, not Numeric

Comment: Any suggestion for making E3 to come after E1?

Comment: You can use what @JW posted as an answer, so long as indexing and performance costs are negligible (ie. you have a small data set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you are sorting a string and not a number. if you have the standard format of `emp_id` as `EXXX` where `x` are the numbers then you can replace `E` and `cast` the remaining into int.

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee_master
ORDER  BY CAST(REPLACE(emp_id, 'E', '') AS UNSIGNED)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05e938/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════╗
║ EMP_ID ║
╠════════╣
║ E1     ║
║ E3     ║
║ E4     ║
║ E5     ║
║ E10    ║
╚════════╝
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have a char-based column, the ordering is LEXICAL, not NUMERICAL. Is there a reason you need the prefixed E? If not, I would recommend adding the E in your output script, and changing it to an INT field removing any non-numeric characters

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use `LENGTH()` in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT emp_id 
FROM employee_master_table 
ORDER BY length(emp_id), emp_id;
```

Output:

```
╔════════╗
║ EMP_ID ║
╠════════╣
║ E1     ║
║ E3     ║
║ E4     ║
║ E5     ║
║ E10    ║
╚════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f8b5/1)

#### [SQLFiddle with more values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69460/3)

Comment: i prefer to use `CHAR_LENGTH` over `LENGTH`. anyway, i didn't get the exact result if i have this records. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6457e/1